# DnsQuery can't get valid address on some specific FQDN

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dns

When I using this code
reference here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831226

I can complier success, but when i use it doing some dns query, the return address is weird, for example: 176.20.31.0 (this shouldn't be a valid address)

Here is my output:

```
C:\dnsq\Debug>dnsq.exe -n tw.media.blizzard.com -t A -s 8.8.8.8
The IP address of the host tw.media.blizzard.com is 176.20.31.0
```

But actually the tw.media.blizzard.com should be: (I query it by nslookup)

```
# nslookup tw.media.blizzard.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
tw.media.blizzard.com   canonical name = tw.media.blizzard.com.edgesuite.net.
tw.media.blizzard.com.edgesuite.net     canonical name = a1479.g.akamai.net.
Name:   a1479.g.akamai.net
Address: 23.14.93.167
Name:   a1479.g.akamai.net
Address: 23.14.93.157
```

My question is why dnsquery doesn't work on some FQDN?
Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Luke, the code i use was from MicroSoft:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831226/en

is this what you want? or you just point out the code which MS provide has some problem?

Comment: Are you sure the IP address is actually "wrong"?  Flushing the dns cache between subsequent nslookup commands for that domain gives me different results, even addresses on completely different networks.  It's Akamai so it is likely to be content delivery network technology at play.

Comment: Luke, thanks for pointing out. I'll give it a try and will post bmy finding back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

For those FQDN which leading to invlid address, the common thing are all of their DNS record type are "DNS_TYPE_CNAME", not DNS_TYPE_A.

So we need to parse the whole PDNS_RECORD to get DNS_TYPE_A information.

---

I'll post my change here:

Original code from MS:

```
    if(wType == DNS_TYPE_A) {
        //convert the Internet network address into a string
        //in Internet standard dotted format.
        ipaddr.S_un.S_addr = (pDnsRecord->Data.A.IpAddress);
        printf("The IP address of the host %s is %s \n", pOwnerName,inet_ntoa(ipaddr));

        // Free memory allocated for DNS records. 
        DnsRecordListFree(pDnsRecord, freetype);
    }
```

My change here:

```
    if(wType == DNS_TYPE_A) {
        //convert the Internet network address into a string
        //in Internet standard dotted format.
        PDNS_RECORD cursor;

        for (cursor = pDnsRecord; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->pNext) {
            if (cursor->wType == DNS_TYPE_A) {
                ipaddr.S_un.S_addr = (cursor->Data.A.IpAddress);
                printf("The IP address of the host %s is %s \n", pOwnerName,inet_ntoa(ipaddr));                 
            }
        }

        // Free memory allocated for DNS records. 
        DnsRecordListFree(pDnsRecord, freetype);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PDNS_RECORD pQueryResults;

DNS_STATUS dResult = DnsQuery_A(
        "www.facebook.com",
        DNS_TYPE_A,
        DNS_QUERY_WIRE_ONLY, 
        NULL,
        (PDNS_RECORD*)&pQueryResults,
        NULL
    );

char* szActualHost = (char*) pQueryResults->Data.CNAME.pNameHost;
```

Thanks a lot for sharing this but I would like to add this for further clarification;

- Even if you call DNSQuery_A with DNS_TYPE_A as wType for some FQDN, it may still return you a record for wType as (0x5) DNS_TYPE_CNAME.
- In such cases you can find the actual host name by inspecting the actual CNAME part of the QueryResults and ofcourse call the DNSQuery_A() API for the new hostname again. Check the above Code snipette